# How can I stop Tox from overwriting junit.xml files and test names when running pytest in several python versions?

Tags: pytest, tox

In my CI/CD pipeline the test processing step looks for junit xml files and reports the results. I am using Tox to run pytest for python versions 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9.

Initially Tox was replacing the junit.xml generated for 3.6 with the junit.xml from 3.7, 3.7 with 3.8, etc. but by passing `--junitxml="junit-{envname}.xml"` and updating the CI/CD config to look for `junit-*.xml` I was able to keep results for each environment.

However, test results are reported by test module and name, and because the same tests run in each tox environment, the results still show later environment results overwriting the earlier ones.

I had tried to add `junit_suite_name = "project-{envname}"` but the variable replacement doesn't work the same way here, and my junit suite name is literally `project-{envname}` for all environments now. My goal was to somehow prefix test names with "py36", "py37", etc. so the test names would be different.

In case it matters, I am using Bamboo for CI/CD.

Comment: might have to potentially use --> https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html#record-xml-attribute to modify the test name to append the current environment version

Comment: @gold_cy thanks! This led me to my solution.

Comment: my pleasure, glad you were able to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

As @gold_cy in the comment above mentioned, I was able to use `record-xml-attribute` to solve this issue.

```
import sys
_ver = f"{sys.version_info[0]}_{sys.version_info[1]}"

def test_graph(record_xml_attribute):
    record_xml_attribute("classname", f"test_class_{_ver}")
    ...
```

seems to have worked for me. `3_6`, `3_7`, etc. are added on to the class name for me now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to supplying the environment name to your JUnit file name, you can use the `--junit-prefix` option of `pytest` that will prepend a prefix to the classnames in your JUnit XML output. Depending on the CI/CD system, the command will look similar to:

```sh
pytest --junitxml=junit-{envname}.xml --junit-prefix={envname}
```